# Cookies won't accept a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Look at this code:

```
if(HR.readyState==4 && HR.status==200)
{   
    idUsuarioGlobal=HR.responseText;
    alert("ValorRetornado="+idUsuarioGlobal);
    document.cookie="IDUsuarioGlobal="+idUsuarioGlobal;
    alert(document.cookie);
}
```

The first alert returns: `ValorRetornado=3` just as expected, but the second returns an empty cookie `IDUsuarioGlobal=`; when it should have return `IDUsuarioGlobal=3`

Now this is the odd thing, in the next example everything work as expected when I provied directly the `IdUsuarioGlobal` value, both alerts return the desired value. What Am i doing wrong?

Something else, I have confirmed that HR.response text returns the desired value.

```
if(HR.readyState==4 && HR.status==200)
{   
   idUsuarioGlobal=HR.responseText;
   alert("ValorRetornado="+idUsuarioGlobal);
   document.cookie="IDUsuarioGlobal=3";
   alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: What is the `length` of `HR.responseText` or `idUsuarioGlobal`? There may be additional whitespace around the intended value affecting the `cookie`. You might try either [URL-encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or [trimming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the value.

Comment: Thanks alot, trimming it was the solution. Is there a way to post your comment as an answer?